# {% csrf_token %} is not working in django

Tags: python, django

Template includes just only html forms and it says CSRF token missing or incorrect.

Error:
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
Reason given for failure:
CSRF token missing or incorrect.
template:

```
<form method='POST'>
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col'>
      <input value={{ option1 }} type='submit' class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block button" name='option'/>
    </div>
    <div class='col'>
      <input value={{ option2 }} type='submit' class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block button" name='option'/>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Code for views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from .forms import QuestionForm, OptionForm, UserForm
from .models import User, Question, Choices

def QuestionAnswer(request, user_id, user, question_id):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    question = Question.objects.all().filter(user=user)
    option = Choices.objects.all().filter(question = question[0])    
    return render(request, 'quiz/QuestionAnswer.html', {
        'question':question[0].question,
        'option1':option[0],
        'option2':option[1],
    })
```

Comment: add your imports please

Comment: Please extend you error description beyond "is not working"!

Comment: Can you show your MIDDLEWARE in settings.py, 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware' must be in the list

Comment: Yes `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` is in the list

Comment: ok. should work :/ there is no action in your form tag, can you show your urls.py

Comment: I saw a notification for your comment with urls.py. But i can't see it in the post. Can you add it in your question ?

Answer (score 0):

```
{% load static %}
<form method='POST'>
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col'>
      <input value={{ option1 }} type='submit' class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block button" name='option'/>
    </div>
    <div class='col'>
      <input value={{ option2 }} type='submit' class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block button" name='option'/>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```